# Verification that sphere SDE has same Itô form as Stratonovich

Tags: solution-verification, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a SDE system for Brownian motion on the sphere in spherical coordinates, in particular
$$d \theta_t = \frac12 \cot \theta_t dt + dB_t^1$$
$$d \phi_t =\frac{1}{\sin \theta_t} dB_t^2$$
where $B=(B^1,B^2)$ is a standard planar BM.

If we let $A=(\theta, \phi)^T$ we can write this in vector form
$$dA_t=\mu(A)dt+\sigma(A) dB_t$$
where $\mu =(\frac12 \cot \theta, 0)^T$ and
$$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\sin \theta} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

To convert to Stratonovich, we need to compute
$$2c_i=\sum_k \sum_j \sigma_{kj} \frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_k}$$
where $(x_1, x_2)=(\theta, \phi)$ for notational convenience. Since the off diagonals are zero and its a 2 dimensional case we simplify this as
$$2c_i = \frac{\partial \sigma_{i1}}{\partial \theta} +\frac{1}{\sin \theta}\frac{\partial \sigma_{i2}}{\partial \phi}$$
Substituting the values of $\sigma$ and computing the derivatives we see that $c$ is the zero vector identically. Therefore the Stratonovich SDE is identical (same drift, same diffusion coefficients) to the Itô SDE.

**My Question**
Are these computations and is this conclusion correct?